# Unity - C# Script Variables will not show up in Inspector Window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Pretty much as described in the title- no matter what I do, the Unity Inspector Window refuses to edit any variable whatsoever. I have tried adding public prefixes.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated and I am using Unity 2023.2.6f1.

I have tried fixing with serialization, and I have tried to see if any other script on Stack Overflow works with the Unity Inspector and nothing seems to appease it.

Comment: Your screenshot shows you are making a custom editor, but your custom editor is neither referencing any `MonoBehaviour` derived class, nor does it draw anything. Are you sure you really want to make a custom editor?

Comment: Why are you extending Editor?

Comment: Was your plan to make a custom [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a class with a variable visible in `Editor`, you should use `MonoBehaviour` class. `CustomEditor` classes are used to implement additional logic that is executed in `Editor` mode.

```
public class Move: MonoBehaviour
{ 
  public int Value;
}
```

Comment: Hello Everyone, thank you all I appreciate the help so far!

Unfortunately, I've tried everything suggested so far and nothing seems to be working. I am going back through the Unity pathway tutorial and still can't seem to get it to show. Currently I have this as the script in Move.cs:

```using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string myMessage;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(myMessage);
    }
}```